# Using Microsoft Access, VBA and SQL - what is the simplest way to create a backup table that is appropriately named

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm looking for a simple and creative way to backup a table using VBA and/or SQL.

I need the backup table name to include the backup table name, the date and time it was backed up and the number of records the table held at the time of backup.

I'm using...

```
    CurrentDb.Execute ("SELECT * INTO [tblName BU " & CStr(Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD HHmmss")) & " Records=> " & CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblNameImBackingUp").RecordCount & "] FROM tblNameImBackingUp;")
```

Is there anything better?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with
Docmd.copyobject to make and exact copy.

Comment: Please add some additional details to this so that it is clear to readers exactly what they need to do--perhaps a sample.

Answer (score 0):

> simple and creative way

No. You don't want creative.  You want reliable and easy-to-read.  When something breaks 6 months in the future and needs to be fixed ASAP, you need to be able to read the code quickly and pinpoint the problem.

My recommendation is to store ALL the backups in a single table with an additional field for the backup date. The Insert query would look something like:

```
Insert into [TblBackups]
    Select *, now() from [tblNameImBackingUp];
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to have a look at the INSERT INTO  SQL statement

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Fred if you want to store the backup in the same DB. If you want to move it out of the DB, take a look at DoCmd.TransferDatabase.